# Trouble with port forwarding (VLANS)

Tags: windows

I\'m trying to setup port forwarding on a home router (Motorola Netopia) 
but the already setup VLans are preventing internet traffic to be forwarded on to internal IPs.

Internet Access is no problem, so the question is : whether these VLans are causing this issue or is it something else. I checked, the ISP is not blocking any ports.

If someone can help me with this that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

VLANs cause IP packets to be tagged with additional information indicating which VLAN they belong to.  This can cause issues if your network adapter driver or TCP/IP stack doesn't support VLANs or isn't set to accept frames from the same VLAN (or isn't set to accept frames from any VLAN).

I don't know the Netopia commands to disable VLANs off the top of my head but I would suggest you reset the router and configure it from scratch.  It's unlikely that it's configured with VLANs by factory default.